# Wavelet Transform Graph Is Incorrect. Unsure How to Fix

Tags: graphing, wavelet-transform, pywavelets

I have code for my wavelet transform using a morlet wave. I am using a pandas dataframe which has 4 emg columns within it. Here is my code

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pywt

# List of column names for which you want to generate the Morlet wavelet transform
columns_to_process = ['VL_R', 'VM_R', 'VM_L', 'VL_L']

# Parameters for the Morlet wavelet transform
fs = 100  # Sample rate of EEG data
freqs = np.arange(1, 50, 1)  # Adjust the frequency range as needed
scales = fs / freqs  # Scales for Morlet wavelets

# Create subplots for each column
num_columns = len(columns_to_process)
fig, axs = plt.subplots(num_columns, 1, figsize=(10, 4 * num_columns))

for i, column in enumerate(columns_to_process):
    # Apply a moving average for smoothing 
    smoothed_data = df_cleaned[column].rolling(window=10).mean()

    # Generate Morlet wavelet transform
    coefficients, frequencies = pywt.cwt(smoothed_data, scales, 'morl')

    # Plot Morlet wavelet transform
    im = axs[i].imshow(np.abs(coefficients), extent=[0, len(smoothed_data)/fs, freqs.min(), freqs.max()], aspect='auto', cmap='jet')
    axs[i].set_title(f'{column} Morlet Wavelet Transform')
    axs[i].set_ylabel('Frequency [Hz]')
    axs[i].set_xlabel('Time [sec]')

    # Add colorbar
    cbar = plt.colorbar(im, ax=axs[i])
    cbar.set_label('Magnitude')

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

When I run this, I get something that looks like this

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JbNxt.png)

Is this currently graphing scale and mislabeling it as frequency on the graph? If so, how do I change this code to look right and use frequency instead. Sorry I am new to coding and am trying to use this for research

Answer (score 0):

Good catch.

As you guessed, the frequency axis is flipped upside down.
You can figure this out by taking a look at the cone of influence on the left-hand side.

As per [the mathworks documentation](https://es.mathworks.com/help/wavelet/ug/boundary-effects-and-the-cone-of-influence.html) *[edge-effect artefacts] are effects in the scalogram that arise from areas where the stretched wavelets extend beyond the edges of the observation interval*. The lower the frequency, the more stretched the wavelet becomes, and the wider the cone of influence: so low frequencies should show up in the upper left corner.

You may fix this by changing the `origin` parameter in imshow from the default `upper` to `lower`:

`im = axs[i].imshow(np.abs(coefficients), extent=[0, len(smoothed_data)/fs, freqs.min(), freqs.max()], aspect='auto', cmap='jet', origin = 'lower')`.